# Can an Medium Enlarged PC pick up and wield a Large Weapon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Scenario:

A PC has become Large through means of Enlarge Person. All of the gear he carries has been Enlarged with him as per [Enlarge Person](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person) spell. 
A Large Greatsword lies on the ground nearby and he goes and picks it up. Does the greatsword:

A: Remain Large allowing the PC to wield it just as the equipment enlarged with him?

Follow up: 
What happens when the PC returns to their original size?

Can a Medium PC then carry around a Large weapon on their back, drop it before Enlarge Person is cast, then pick it up and wield it?

B: Enlarge by one size into a Huge Greatsword as soon as it is picked up by the Enlarged PC

C: do something I haven't thought of....?

Comment: Building a character based tactics related to this. Wanted to see if it was at all viable or if it just wouldn't work at all

Comment: @7seasJ  Generally speaking question tags should be directly relevant to your question.  Your question doesn't mention that you need to know for character creation, so your question is left with a confusing and unrelated tag.   I recommend adding context to your question so that it makes sense with that tag.

Comment: @LegendaryDude My mistake, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 6):

I believe that A is correct RAW,

### items picked up after receiving [Enlarge Person](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person) would not change size.

I base this on:

"All equipment worn or carried by a creature is similarly enlarged by the spell." BUT "Any enlarged item that leaves an enlarged creature's possession (including a projectile or thrown weapon) instantly returns to its normal size. This means that thrown and projectile weapons deal their normal damage."

This reads to me as objects not on you at the time of the spell cast are not affected. Only objects that you were carrying are increased. I understand the other interpretation, but Enlarge Person isn't an effect that you carry with you (like a Silence spell) it's a transmutation that alters they way you are for a period of time. It doesn't affect your environment.

Answer (score 3):

### All items wielded by the character are enlarged, regardless of when they're picked up

As per the text of [Enlarge Person](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person)

> All equipment worn or carried by a creature is similarly enlarged by the spell

Now let's look at the pathfinder [spell rules](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magic.html), specifically the Duration header
And the spell has a duration that is not instantaneous, so the duration is a timed duration

> Timed Durations: Many durations are measured in rounds, minutes, hours, or other increments. When the time is up, the magic goes away and the spell ends. If a spell's duration is variable, the duration is rolled secretly so the caster doesn't know how long the spell will last.

And it affects a creature directly, so

> Subjects, Effects, and Areas: If the spell affects creatures directly, the result travels with the subjects for the spell's duration. If the spell creates an effect, the effect lasts for the duration. The effect might move or remain still.

Therefore, we know that the "equipment (...) carried by the creature" effect moves with the creature, and lasts for the duration of the spell, meaning that any items picked up by the creature after the moment of casting are also affected by the spell and enlarged.

Therefor to answer your specific scenarios:

A: The weapon would go up another size category to Huge, making the greatsword unwieldable by any Large or smaller creature. When the PC drops the weapon or the duration ends, the greatsword becomes Large again.

B: This is what happens, the sword enlarges and is unwieldable (see [the Weapon Size heading](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons) for details) for as long as the enlarged PC is carrying it.

Comment: @7seasJ Thanks for accepting my answer! I have confidence in it, but it's usually a good idea to wait for other competing answers in case they find something that contradicts this one. If more answers pop up, feel free to switch to one of them, and definitely give them a read